# Return fields that are related to a model by a foreignkey

Tags: python, django

```
class SenderInfo(models.Model):
    #to create unique id numbers
    sender = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    id_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
class Messages(models.Model):
    message_sender = models.ForeignKey(SenderInfo, related_name='messages')
    message_body = models.TextField()
```

I want to just return all the messages for each instance of `SenderInfo`. So I can see all the messages a user has made. I know how to see the Senders of a particular message but what's the simplest method to achieve the opposite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return a queryset with all messages:

```
sender.messages_set.all()
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `sender` is an instance of `SenderInfo`.

Comment: Sorry replied to the wrong answer, I've tried this before but the error I get is "object has not attribute " messages_set"

Comment: You declared `related_name='messages'`. So it should be `sender_info_instance.messages.all()` for the [reverse related manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/).

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform thank you man, I took way too long on this issue. Youre great

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

**views.py**

```
sender_infos = SenderInfo.objects.all()
```

**HTML template**

```
{% for sender_info in sender_infos %}
    {{sender_info.sender}}
    {{sender_info.id_number}}
    {% for message in  sender_info.messages_set.all %}
        {{message.message_sender}}
        {{message.message_body}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```